# Как можно реализовать вывод ObservableCollection в ходе работы программы WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать программу, одной из важных частей которой, будет вывод информации по ходу её работы. В ходе работы программы, необходимые данные для вывода заполняют `ObservableCollection`. Но как вывести её содержимое?

```
public ICollection<string> TextBlock
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(_CleanLog._CleanLog); }
}

public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> TextBlocks => _CleanLog.CleanLog;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72528/discussion-on-question-by-medbed-----observablecollectio).

Comment: Решение оказалось простым избавился от `ReadOnly` в Model и ViewModel.